# Google Cloud Datalow:Getting a below error at runtime

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing data into nested array BQ table(array name inside the table is -merchant_array)using my dataflow template.
Sometime its running fine and loading the data but sometime its giving me that error at run time.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?) (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow["null"])
```

"message" : "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 223615: Only optional fields can be set to NULL. Field: merchant_array; Value: NULL",

[image]
Anyone has any idea why I am getting this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose this is json serialization error.

Comment: Due to this "NULL" value? But why getting null.

Comment: Looks like your input data contains records that aren't valid according to the schema you have set.  Where is your data coming from, and what is the schema you are using?

Comment: Data is coming from one table.The schema is correct but when the loop is iterating on source iterable data that time it is putting null for some tablerow.  sourceValuesIterable.parallelStream().forEach(tblRow ->
  {
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I got the issue that was causing error so I am posting my own question's answer,it might be helpful for anyone.

So the error was like-
Only optional fields can be set to NULL. Field: merchant_array; Value: NULL",

And here merchant_array is defined as an array that contains record (repetitive) data.
As per google [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) the the array can not be-
ARRAYs cannot be NULL.
NULL ARRAY elements cannot persist to a table.

At the same time I was using arraylist in my code, that allows null values. So before making a record type data in code or setting the data in arraylist, just remove the NULL  tablerows if exist.

hope this will helpful.